# How to write a tool to change .net code (for obfuscation purposes)

Tags: .net, obfuscation

For my thesis I am creating a tool/script that obfuscates .NET code. The goal is to use a technique called control flow graph flattening before compiling the code and in this way obfuscate the control flow of the program.

A example of a code change that would need to happen is this (not my picture):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnlzc.png

My problem at this point is that I do not know how to automatically change the code in certain situations. Are there tools that i can use that allow me to specify what should be changed? Should I focus on something like python?

Answer (score 1):

I am an author or [ArmDot](https://www.armdot.com/), a tool that supports control flow obfuscation as well. The idea of control flow obfuscation is to hide actual execution flow.

I am not sure about python, I think it's a good idea to use .net to make such tool. Have a look at [dnlib](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib), and [mono/cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil) that both provide similar API to read, write and manipulate IL code. It seems that dnlib popularity grows, but I do prefer cecil.

Just split original instructions into sequences at points where execution flow changes (there are instructions that change execution flow, like `br`, `br.false`, `beq` and others; you definitely should use [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) as a reference).

Then introduce a variable that stores current sequence index. Make a big `switch` that executes sequences depending on current sequence index.

Replace instructions that change execution flow with instructions that calculate next sequence index. For `br` next sequence index is obvious, for `br.false` you need to pop a value from stack to get next index depending on popped value.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have close to no experience manipulating IL code, do you think it is possible for me to learn this and apply it to make an obfuscator in 2 months (I also have an internship in these 2 months)? 

Is the result of changing the IL code and high-level code a lot different? I'm wondering this since I saw a defcon talk about CFG flattening before compiling. 

If you don't think it is possible for me to implement CFG flattening in those 2 months, can you think of another obfuscation technique i could take a look at?